# Executing a script after every login / password entry in Windows

Tags: batch-file, timer, windows-task-scheduler

How can I schedule a (batch-) script to be executed after every Windows log-in (not only after boot-up, but after every screenlock + PIN-entry)?

(Background: I want to code an automatic reminder to make a break after an hour, stand up and move a bit. The timer shall be restarted after every log-in into Windows (not only reboot, but screen-lock + PIN entry). In case no screen-lock is done within 5 minutes after an alarm, the alarm shall be retriggered. No third party programs allowed^^)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Task Scheduler, use the trigger "On workstation unlock".

This will cover you for not only boot-up, but also after every PIN entry when the screen is locked.